# UWP Can't upload Store Logo for Scale 200 in appxmanifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, uwp, appxmanifest

I created a project in C# in Visual Studio. Now I want to upload a store logo in many different sizes. So, the first thing I saw was, that you have to upload so many scales of an image size(Scale 400, 200, 100, 150, 125).
Thank God, there is a helpful App in the Windows Store (Universal Asset Creator). So I only need to upload one store logo there an I will get the images in different sizes and scales.
If I upload these images in to my appxmanifest, I'll get this message:

> A mixture of Images with and without the "scale" or "targetsize" qualifiers exists in this project for the logical name "Assets\VisualAssets\71x71Logo.scale-200_white.png". When a mixture exists, files without the qulifier will be ignored. For predictable runtime behavior, explicitly specify the scale for each image asset.

This is only happening for the Scale 200 image of **every size**.

What do I have to do?

Thank you for helping,

Chris

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem. Have you double checked that you do not have a Assets\VisualAssets\71x71Logo.png (or any file without targetsize or scale) in your assets? Besides, the app does not produce contrast related files, how did you get 71x71Logo.scale-200_white.png from it?

Comment: Hi Mehrzad. i've already checked this. Every file has targetsize or scale in the name. You can choose a theme suffix in this app.

Comment: I recreated the store logos without choosing a theme suffix - same result, same names.

Comment: Have you tried to clear/rebuild the solution? you can also try removing obj and bin folders in the project.

Comment: yes.. have already done this.. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

For the 71x71Logo.scale,you can edit the pic manully.
You can try to use the paint tooland edit the pixel by yourself,after that you can put the logo in the right position.
First open the pic with Paint tool.
Then click Resize.
Finally choose pixel.
And then you can edit on your own.
Hope it will be helpful to you.

[edit the pixel manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLDVE.jpg)

Comment: Hi, i resized the images in paint and also in photoshop. Getting the same error messages...